# ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) Projects instance [my-project] not found: The requested flag is either misspelled or unsupported by Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When I try to create cloud sql instance using gcloud I got this error. Any thoughts folks?

```
--database-version=$DB_VERSION \
--cpu=$NUMBER_CPUS \
--memory=$MEMORY_SIZE \
--storage-type=$STORAGE_TYPE \
--storage-size=$STORAGE_SIZE \
--storage-auto-increase \
--database-flags=$DATABASE_FLAGS \
--region=$REGION \
--authorized-networks=$NETWORKS \
--assign-ip \
--project=$PROJECT_ID
```

It doesnt mater enabled projectId or not in this command
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue recently and turns out it was caused by an incorrectly spelled DB flag. You can verify that your flags are correct by using this gcloud command -
`gcloud sql flags list --project=${PROJECT_ID} --database-version=${DATABASE_VERSION}`
This lists out all the flags supported for the given database.